# How can I install solr@7.7 with homebrew

Tags: macos, installation, solr, homebrew

Trying to install solr@7.7 on Mac Venturna by running

```
brew install solr@7.7
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: solr@7.7 has been disabled because it is not supported upstream!
```

OS version(13.6)

Answer (score 0):

I found on solution,
we can use the following script here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/2fc04d097059c0291dfeef9e6e9c0e60d3daef86/Formula/s/solr@7.7.rb

download the script, and comment out this statement

```
# disable! date: "2023-06-19", because: :unsupported
```

then run the following command

```
brew install solr@7.7.rb
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that solr@7.7 seems not to be compatible with Ventura (13.6.)

You disable the version check by commenting it in the brew install script.

So you may get a lot of problems later. I would suggest to

- upgrade your os 13.6
- or to downgrade the sol from 7.7
- wait for a compatible version